# parsing json feed and save the details in shared preference?

Tags: android, json, authentication

this is my `json` feed

i need to store the email and password in shared preference and need to check whwn the user enters .. if it is right i should show a messsage.. otheriwse i should register

Comment: Have you parsed the json string?

Comment: can u help mee.. i dont know to do it..

Comment: You have tons of Tutorial buddy for JSON parsing please look at them.

Comment: i parsed the details from the feed .. again i need to save the email and passowrd from that feed in shared preference..

Comment: look at shared Preferences tutorials.

Comment: i looked a lot but not getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To Parse the JSON**

```
JSONObject objMain = new JSONObject("String");
JSONObject memberDetail = objMain.optJSONObject("member_details");
String unm = memberDetail.optString("username");
String pwd = memberDetail.optString("password");
```

**To Store it to SharedPreferences**

```
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Editor ed = sp.edit();
    ed.putString("unm", unm);
    ed.putString("pwd", pwd);
    ed.commit();
```

**To Read from SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences sp1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String unmStored = sp1.getString("unm","");
String pwdStored = sp1.getString("pwd","");
```

Comment: are you a developer? use if condition and to check stored one and new.